# Is there any way to create a skyblock map with structures spawning? (I want normal Nether + End)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I want to use the second skyblock map (the orginal skyblock map with a sand island with a cactus) and make normal (and modded) overworld structures spawn in the void.
How can I do this?